# OneDrive - Correct Oauth, Scope, and Service Endpoint Combination

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

My Requirements are to access a User's OneDrive account with my app (i.e. to be able to read/write into my App Folder.) and to get the User's information (name/email) I have registered my App ... And that seems to be working because I get to approve my scopes when I try to login to my account. I am having problems when converting a code to an access token, or in some cases when I get an access_token it is invalid for the Service endpoint I am using. I have been working with various combinations of the following:

```
Oauth Options (Code Flow): 
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth/v2/authorize
    https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf
Scopes Varients (With/Without endpoint prefix):
    Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder
    OneDrive.AppFolder
Service Endpoints:
    https://graph.microsoft.com/
    https://api.onedrive.com/
```

My latest is with the first option from each above ... but even though it recognized my application when it asked me to approve the scope and provided a code. .. it said it could not recognize my application when it tried to convert the code to a token:

> {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS70001:
>   Application with identifier '0000000048240701' was not found in the
>   directory 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad\r\nTrace ID:
>   87f0c3e6-0d9f-4ccf-b3e9-c7d43b422800\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   7f440db6-eba9-4a0c-8d1f-54ae5c21d0cd\r\nTimestamp: 2018-08-30
>   16:12:38Z","error_codes":[70001],"timestamp":"2018-08-30
>   16:12:38Z","trace_id":"87f0c3e6-0d9f-4ccf-b3e9-c7d43b422800","correlation_id":"7f440db6-eba9-4a0c-8d1f-54ae5c21d0cd"}

Can anyone recommend the correct set of options I should be focusing on ?

My current code declarations:

```
private static String sClientID = "75417aa8-5567-4095-97fa-e09da6e1d8fb";
private static String sClientSecret = "LzAmOFF13Hgzob ... ";
private static String sCodeURL  = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%s&scope=%s&response_type=code&state=%s&redirect_uri=%s";
private static String sScope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder";
private static String sTokenURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
private static String sTokenArgs = "code=%s&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&redirect_uri=%s";
private static String sAPIRootURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
```

All arguments are URL encoded when inserted into the URLs.

Removing the Query parameter from the redirect URI solved the token request problem. I used the same redirect URI for both the Authorization request and the Token request. The fact that the first worked is what confused me.  I am also using  a "Converged" app ID based on suggestion from Marc. I still get an error with the my first api request: 
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/

My java code is:

```
String _url = sAPIRootURL + "/me/";
u = new URL(_url);
uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", 
mSessionInfo.BearerToken));
uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

> { "code": "BadRequest",   "message": "The MIME type 'text/html,
>   image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2' requires a '/' character
>   between type and subtype, such as 'text/plain'.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "f627bd8a-bc3a-4bb4-928a-a0daf7112368",
>         "date": "2018-09-05T01:28:59"
>        }

I verified the the Token request response included the User.Read scope.

[image: App Registration]

Comment: How/where did you register your app?

Comment: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Comment: Did you register it under "Azure AD only applications" or under "Converged applications"?

Comment: See registration snap above. I originally used Safe Deposit Vault. I added and tried Safe Deposit Vault Web, ... now get error in the token response: "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application" but it called my Token URL ... so I am confused here.

Comment: The Reply Url ( or Redirect Uri) is a URI _you_ host. This is where it will send the Authorization Code. You then need `POST` that auth code _back_ to the `/token` endpoint.

Comment: It did call my Uri ... and when I tried to get exchange the code for a token that is where I got the error ... so that is why I am confused ... it already found this URI to call me with the code.

Comment: My actual uri for callback includes an argument "?CloudProvider=OneDrive" could that be causing the problem ?  Note: I do know how OAuth2 works ... I am successfully using it for GoogleDrive and Dropbox.

Comment: Your redirect URI shouldn't include any query params. You may want to read this primer on using the v2 Endpoint: https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/

Comment: See my updated Question for latest issue.

Comment: OK I resolved my last issue. I needed to add the following header for the API call:      Accept: application/json   I am now working ... Thanks for the help. A CURL example would be a lot clearer ... so there is no ambiguity of what is required.